# Android: How to repeat list items in listview

Tags: android, listview, items

I am developing an android app, i have to display a list view with duplicate items. Originally the list view is showing 3 items but i want them to be displayed 3 or 4 times. Is there any way to do that?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HireGroups> {

ArrayList<HireGroups> result;
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HireGroups> list) {
    super(context,0, list);
    c=context;
    result=list;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return result.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    final HireGroups h = result.get(position);
    if(h.getSubHireGroup().size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;

    final HireGroups i = result.get(position);
    if(i != null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_hiregroup_item, null);
        final TextView hireGroupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_name);
        final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        final TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_desc);
        final ImageView hiregroupImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_image);
        final TextView vehicleCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_of_vehicles);

        if(hireGroupName != null) {
            hireGroupName.setText(i.getHireGroupName());
        }
        if(subtitle != null) {
            subtitle.setText(i.getSubTitle());
        }
        if(hiregroupImage != null) {
            Picasso.with(c).load(i.getPhotoUrl()).into(hiregroupImage);
        }
        if(desc != null) {
            desc.setText(i.getDescription());
        }
        if(vehicleCount != null)
        {
            int count=i.getSubHireGroup().size();
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
            anim.setStartOffset(20);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            if(count > 0)
            {
                vehicleCount.startAnimation(anim);
                vehicleCount.setText("  "+count+" Available ");
            }
            else
                vehicleCount.setText("  "+count+" Available ");
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: What source is your Listview using. ArrayList or Cursor?

Comment: It is an arraylist of a class objects that gets populated from a json string.

Comment: create a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` and "wraps" the original one and override `getCount` returning 3 or 4 times more then your original adapter does

Comment: Just populate the arraylist thrice from the json string and each time just add the json object to arraylist

Comment: i have an adapter, u can see my edit.

Comment: so return `3 * result.size()` from `getCount` and apply modulo `result.size()` operation to any `position` in your adapter

Comment: @pskink yes thanks it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to display the same data 3 times, then what you can do is

modify the **getCount()** like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return result.size() * 3;
}
```

and modify the **getView()**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;

    final HireGroups i = result.get(position % 3);
    if(i != null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_hiregroup_item, null);
        final TextView hireGroupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_name);
        final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        final TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_desc);
        final ImageView hiregroupImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hire_group_image);
        final TextView vehicleCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_of_vehicles);

        if(hireGroupName != null) {
            hireGroupName.setText(i.getHireGroupName());
        }
        if(subtitle != null) {
            subtitle.setText(i.getSubTitle());
        }
        if(hiregroupImage != null) {
            Picasso.with(c).load(i.getPhotoUrl()).into(hiregroupImage);
        }
        if(desc != null) {
            desc.setText(i.getDescription());
        }
        if(vehicleCount != null)
        {
            int count=i.getSubHireGroup().size();
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
            anim.setStartOffset(20);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            if(count > 0)
            {
                vehicleCount.startAnimation(anim);
                vehicleCount.setText("  "+count+" Available ");
            }
            else
                vehicleCount.setText("  "+count+" Available ");
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: i had already tried multiplying the result.size() * 3 but didn't applied modulus while retrieving the item so i was getting  exception. originally @pskink deserves the credit for this answer. Thanks to you too.